# Populating checkbox values from a LINQ query?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, linq

I'm trying to populate the checked values on a checkboxlist based upon a LINQ query. But I am having trouble figuring out how to do this.

I have an `Enum` called UserRoles and on page load I bind the checkbox list to the enum values, and descriptions.

```
 uRoles.DataSource = RiseBi.Enumeration.GetEnumDescriptions(GetType(UserTypes))
 uRoles.DataTextField = "Value"
 uRoles.DataValueField = "Key"
```

Next to get the user roles:

```
Public Shared Function GetAllUserRoles(ByVal EID As Integer) As IQueryable(Of RiseDB.UserRole)
        Dim DB As New RiseDB.RiseDBContainer
        Dim tmp = (From p In DB.Users Where p.Id = EID).First
        Return tmp.UserRoles
    End Function
```

What would be the best way to populate the checkboxes for that particular user that matches the roles?

I was thinking just a loop for each value in UserRoles and where they match check it, but there has to be a simpler way, no?

Answer (score 0):

in msdn [CheckBoxList Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.checkboxlist%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

> To determine the selected items in the CheckBoxList control, iterate through the Items collection and test the Selected property of each item in the collection.

so only loop for checking items